Proving Symmedian intersects intersection of tangents
I'm going through Evan Chen's "Euclidean Geometry in Math Olympiads" and I've come to Chapter 4's section on Symmedians.
Proposition 4.24 says:
Let $X$ be the intersection of the tangents to $(ABC)$ at $B$ and $C$. Then line $AX$ is a Symmedian.
To prove it, it says to consider the intersection of the isogonal of $AX$ with $BC$ , $M$ and prove $MC/BM = \sin BAX \star \sin B / \sin CAX \star \sin C = 1$.
I have the first part, $MC/BM = \sin BAX · \sin B / \sin CAX · \sin C$.
Now I just need to prove it's equal to $1$. To do so, I've tried with the law of sines to prove $\sin BAX / \sin CAX = \sin C / \sin B = AB / AC$ , but I don't know how to use it to do so.
If anyone could help me, I'd really appreciate it.

What remains can be proven using law of sines, as you guessed.
Notice that $\angle ABX = 180^\circ - \angle C$, hence we have $\sin \angle ABX = \sin (180^\circ - \angle C) = \sin \angle C$. Similarly, we have$\sin \angle ACX = \sin \angle B$.
Now using law of sines, we can write
$$\dfrac{\sin \angle BAX}{|BX|} = \dfrac{\sin \angle ABX}{|AX|}$$ or equivalently, we have $$\sin \angle BAX = \dfrac{|BX|}{|AX|} \cdot \sin \angle C$$ and similarly we have $$\sin \angle CAX = \dfrac{|CX|}{|AX|} \cdot \sin \angle B.$$ Dividing the last two equalities side-by-side, and using the fact that $|BX|=|CX|$, we obtain $$ \dfrac{\sin \angle BAX}{\sin \angle CAX} = \dfrac{\sin \angle C}{\sin \angle B}$$ which is the same as $$ \boxed{ \dfrac{\sin \angle BAX \cdot \sin \angle B}{\sin \angle CAX \cdot \sin \angle C} = 1 } $$ as desired.

Oh, thanks! It didn't ocurr to me to put $\angle ABX = \angle A + \angle B$ into $\angle ABX = 180° - \angle C$ It's a neat trick, and I'll have it in mind for future problems. Thanks a lot!
